# Could we train an AI to find (only) Mersenne primes and beat the current record?

Tags: algorithms

Could we train an AI to find only Mersenne primes and beat the current record $2 ^ {82 589 933} - 1$?

A Mersenne number is a number of the form $2 ^ n - 1$ (where n is a non-zero natural number), a prime Mersenne number (sometimes Mersenne prime number), is therefore a prime number of this form.

There is an efficient primality test for Mersenne numbers, the Lucas-Lehmer primality test, which makes the largest known prime numbers Mersenne numbers.

The prime Mersenne numbers are however rare: 51 are known at the start of 2020. Their research is the subject of a collaborative computing project, the GIMPS project.

With $2 ^ n-1 = p$ There is only one input n, to provide to the IA and only one output p, either prime or not, and a lot of data to train this IA up to $n = 82589933$ where we have all the inputs n and the outputs p.

An IA has an error rate but a super-trained IA has a reduced error rate and can infer whether p is prime or not if the input $n> 82589933$.

Comment: Even if you train an AI and it outputs "yes", how do you plan to confirm that this result is correct?

Comment: the Lucas-Lehmer primality test.But you need a well-trained AI with a very low error rate which always finds the 51st result before giving it a list n>82589933.

Comment: most alghorihtme takes a long time there is a lot of input and output and working with the value of p, here I just have a ridiculous input number n = 82589933 and p = 0 or 1 and I have just 51 cases where p = 1 and I let the AI ​​find a model that will be quick, then I provide a new list where n> 82589933 to find where p = 1 ..

Comment: Basically, you want a diff-able function whose roots are Mersenne primes, and you want to find this function using neural networks (if I am guessing correctly). I think for this to be true, something like the Riemann hypothesis has to be true. And also, you need to know more or less the correct form of the function, or at least, the function has to be in your search space. So I will say no.

Comment: @Abdullah Ali Sivas kicks it as usual. What is the idea your AI should be following? What is the model it should learn? It would have to train a function $\mathbb N \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where there is only randomness. More practical: in AI you always need an approach, some kind of system that you want to learn, which is based on a certain kind of regularity. Recent successes in AI were made in topics, where humans have a clue, such as picture recognition. Imho we are far away from applications as you asked for in your post.

Comment: I'm not going to do the primality test to train my AI, I know the position of each prime number up to n = 82589933, there are only 51 prime numbers. The goal would be to train an AI with small lists up to n = 10 then up to n = 100 and so on up to n = 82,589,933, to succeed in machine learning and be able to predict the position of the 52 number. prime in a list greater than 82589933, this is where I will test the primality first on n then on p, because if p is prime, then n is prime

Comment: Note that the 1-neuron neural network that returns "$2^n-1$ is not prime" for each $n$ achieves 99.99993% accuracy on the training set $\{1,2,\dots,82589933\}$. It's going to be difficult to beat that.

Comment: the fact that there are rare prime numbers of mersennes generates less calculation to do to train AI.

I have a list of 0 to 82589933 inputs n which corresponds to a list of 0 to 82589933 outputs p which are all 0 except for 51 cases where they are worth 1. Learning begins with small lists from 0 to 10 then 0 to 100 and so on up to 0 to 82589933 to detect where the output is 1,

Comment: there isn't a lot of calcul to do that. The second learning phase begins with a larger list for example 0 to 1082589933, the AI ​​must provide a position where n is prime and test if p validates the Lucas-Lehmer test, here there would be a calculation to check if n are prime and if the Lucas-Lehmer test works for p, not a lot of calculations to do. And phase 3 consists in verifying if the Lucas-Lehmer test is effective, and that really p is prime, this is where there are a lot of calculations to do, but this is the last step to do and or have cross the must ...

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental difficulty with prime numbers is that for all practice purposes, they are *randomly distributed*. Most theorems (and open problems) about prime numbers -- say, that there are infinitely many prime pairs separated by two -- can be conjectured by assuming that prime numbers are randomly distributed, though actually proving things is of course much harder.

So then what that means in your case is that you want a function $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ that is zero for most arguments except for a very small number of randomly located arguments, where it is one. That would by itself already be a difficult proposition because the function would have no regularity (smoothness) and that makes it very difficult to "learn" such functions: You can't, in general, do much better than simply *tabulating* the places where the function is one.

But you're asking for something even more difficult: You want this learned function to not just represent the *known* arguments, but in fact you want to *extrapolate* beyond the known values. But this requires some kind of smoothness of the function you are trying to learn, something that allows us to *generalize* from what we've learned to what we want to apply it to. But the randomness of prime numbers hits you again here: There is no specific *pattern* to prime numbers, nothing in their bit representations or decimal representations, or anything else that would provide this kind of pattern that one could learn; if there were, prime numbers would be a much simpler kind of object to work with mathematically.